# Why is integral of product of a test function and derivative of Dirac-delta function seems to diverge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, integration, dirac-delta-distributions

Suppose,we have to evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta'(x)dx$

Traditionally to solve this,we integrate by parts so that the integral is equal to$-f'(0)$,which is finite if $0$ is not a pole of the function $f(x)$.But if the following is done the integral diverges---

Differentiating both sides of the well known identity, $x\delta(x)=0 $ we get,
$1.\delta(x)+x\delta'(x)=0\implies \delta'(x)=-\frac{\delta(x)}{x}$.
Putting this in the integral to be evaluated, we have,

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\delta(x)dx=\frac{f(0)}{0}$,which is undefined for any function $f(x)$.Where did this procedure go wrong?Is it related to the fact that delta function is a distribution?If so,How?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Well, for starters, your identity involves dividing by zero...

Comment: You cannot multiply distributions by functions which have singularities. This operation is not defined on distributions, and you did exactly that when multiplying obtained relation by 1/x to get the equation for delta'(x).

Comment: So,it its a property of the delta-distribution which leads to the fallacy!Thanks!

Comment: Also, distributions are only defined through the inner product, which is in this case integration over $\mathbb{R}$. In this framework, $x\delta(x)$ does not make sense, but only its integral over $\mathbb{R}$. You can try and work out the identity in this manner.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about pure mathematics without any physical motivation. I did not migrate it because the claim that $f(0)/0$ is infinite is false - it is simply ill-defined, and why dividing by zero is ill-defined has already been answered many times on [math.SE], so adding another duplicate has no value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say that the delta function is a distribution, we mean that it only has meaning inside of an integral of the form $$ \int_a^b dx f(x) \delta(x)   $$ where $f(x)$ is a smooth test function which vanishes outside of the interval $[a,b]$. Your function $f(x)/x$ is not a smooth test function (it is undefined at $x=0$), so your argument does not apply.

Likewise your "well known identity" $x\delta(x)=0$ only makes sense inside an integral, and is not otherwise an identity at all. It means $$ \int_a^b dx x \delta(x)  = 0. $$ Differentiate $0$ and you get $0$.

Similarly, $\delta'(x)$ only has meaning inside an integral, and is only defined by integration by parts for a valid test function. You cannot use the product rule on a delta function, because it is not a differentiable function.

Comment: My original question is answered itself in the first part of your answer,but $x\delta'(x)=-x$ can be proved without product rule,as given in distributional derivatives section of the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function,and the equation is just written without the integral!
So,does it really still mean that the identity has no meaning outside an integral?

Comment: Yes, the < , > notation used in that proof is an abstract way of writing the integrals, preferred by matmos who want to give a sophisticated answer (good for  a rigorous treatment, not so much for application).

Answer (score 0):

Since, you don't want a highly rigorous answer (per your comment). I would then simply point out that this integration can't be done as the integrand is singular and integral diverges. You may want to look at [Singular Integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularIntegral.html).
One way to do the integral is using contour integration in complex analysis. For example you may look at [Type 4 Integrals](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/372Fa15/coursenotes/Trapper_MethodsContourIntegrals.pdf).
Revert back if you have further doubts.

Comment: Why does the integrand blows up?I think I am making a valid substitution,which maybe should not make the integral singular,and by the way,I deleted that comment because, maybe I was looking for a bit more of rigour (I believe it is needed on doing the substituition and the consequent integral)